# Showing posts based on user activity

Tags: mysql, formula, forum

I am creating a question answer forum (PHP + MySQL). However, I have a section in my page which says Trending questions (Hot questions). 
What I mean by this is those questions which is having maximum user activity currently. User activity can be any of these

1. Upvote the question
2. Answer the question
3. Comment on any particular answer to that question

Now, I want to display the trending questions by calculating a score for each question based on latest timestamp for each of the above items.

Can anyone please suggest how should the score formula be so that questions are sorted based on user activity?

How should my function look like? Should it be linear or exponential or any other?

Comment: are you copying StackOverflow ? :D

Comment: Haha. Not at all dude. It will be totally different from stackoverflow. there will be expert connect and collaborations also but those things are far off to speak now. :P

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function which stores "user activity" temporarily, in a time frame of say 24 hours. Every time a question gets upvoted, the database will register two upvotes: one permanent, one temporary. the temporary upvote will be removed from the database after the given time frame. Then you can display posts on your trending page based on those temporary upvotes. Since the temporary upvotes get removed after a given time frame, your trending page will always show the post which is currently the most active up top.